# How to extract urls from an xml using scrapy - XMLFeedSpider?

Tags: scrapy

I have started using Scrapy recently and I'm trying to use the "XMLFeedSpider" to extract and load the pages that are in a xml page. But the problem is that it is returning an error: "IndexError: list index out of range".

I'm trying to collect and load all product pages that are at this address:
"http://www.example.com/feed.xml"

My spider:

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

class PartySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.example.com']

    start_urls = [      
        'http://www.example.com/feed.xml'
    ]   

    itertag = 'loc'

    def parse_node(self, response, node): 
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag,''.join(node.extract()))
```

Comment: Please share your stacktrace when you get `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Sure, I have added my traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your XML input starts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url><loc>http://www.example.htm</loc></url>
<url><loc>http://www.example.htm</loc></url>
(...)
```

And there's acutally a bug in `XMLFeedSpider` when using (the default) iterator `iternodes` when the XML document uses a namespace. See [this archived discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scrapy-users/VN6409UHexQ/naW7S3w5KggJ) in scrapy-users mailinglist.

This spider works, changing the iterator to `xml`, where you can reference a namespace, here `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9` using the prefix `n` (it could be anything really), and using this namespace prefix for the tag to look for, here `n:loc`:

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

class PartySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    start_urls = [      
        'http://www.example.com/example.xml'
    ]   

    namespaces = [('n', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')]
    itertag = 'n:loc'
    iterator = 'xml'

    def parse_node(self, response, node): 
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag,''.join(node.extract()))
```

Comment: Apparently still a bug because this is the only way I could get it to work too. Which differs from the documentation https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider-example